# Predicted probability values from Logistic regression are negative

Tags: r, probability, logistic, prediction

I have a categorical response which i want to predict, so i am in the process of developing a logistic model.  I am using k-fold cross-validation for model selection. The first model, which was just an intercept model is throwing negative fitted values.

So i tried adding just 2 predictors to understand what was causing this, but the model with the 2 predictors is also predicting negative probabilities.

Below is the code that i used:

```
    logistic_null1 <- glm(SeriousDlqin2yrs ~ 1, family=binomial(), data=trainingdata)

logistic_null1 <- glm(SeriousDlqin2yrs ~ age + income, family=binomial(), data=trainingdata)
```

I checked if may be the response Y is not a factors but doesn't seem to be the case either

```
> class(trainingdata$SeriousDlqin2yrs)
[1] "factor"
> check3 <- as.data.frame(predict(logistic_null1, testdata))
> summary(check3)
 predict(logistic_null1, testdata)
 Min.   :-4.609                   
 1st Qu.:-3.047                   
 Median :-2.700                   
 Mean   :-2.703                   
 3rd Qu.:-2.346                   
 Max.   :-1.601
```

What could cause this

Comment: Questions about how R code works are off topic here. In addition, please consider reading the documentation ([?predict.glm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html)). In particular, note the `type` argument & its default.

Comment: @gung: sorry about that. I was not sure whether it was because of my code or if such a scenario was possible in logistic.

Comment: You have negative predicted values on the log odds scale.  When you convert them into probabilities, they will be in the interval $(0,\ .5)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `?predict.glm`, you can read that by default the type of prediction will be the link function (log odds for logistic regression) instead of probabilities.

You can get predicted probabilities with :

```
predict(logistic_null1, testdata, type="response")
```